# Regex for parsing URL

Tags: php, regex

I am working on parsing urls in the form of http://site.com/page/var1/var2 and I am using the following regex to do so:

```
([^/]+)
```

Now I understand that this takes all values that are not / but I want to also be able to take variables with escaped slashes in them. When I paste these into my browser they end up looking like this: http://site.com/page/var1//stillvar1/var2 which is equal to var1/stillvar1 and var2. My question is bascially how can I modify this regex equation to catch all values which are not / unless / is followed by a slash.

Hopefully I'm being clear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which text are you referring to? It should be any and all things that are not a single slash.

Comment: the text you are extracting it from.

Comment: Its from a URL, the current regex looks as follows: /search/([^/]+)/([^/]+) and its in the form of a request to the server which takes multiple agruments in the url, this is through a framework which allows you to setup routes in the url using mod_rewrite.

Comment: `http://site.com/page/var1//stillvar1/var2` does not contain an escaped slash. `http://site.com/page/var1%2Fstillvar1/var2` does. If you are doing it differently, then you're doing it wrong. Fix your URL encoding before you search regular expressions.

Comment: Please see the related section at the bottom right of this page. 99% of all possible url-parsing-with-regex related questions have been answer on this site.

Comment: @Tomalak, I am encoding it as well now, sorry I have been doing a lot more research since I posted, however when I encode it, as soon as it compared,  var1%252fstillvar1 is being output on the page as var1\/stillvar1 which means apache is most likely decoding it automtically.

Comment: `var1%252fstillvar1` amounts to `var1%2fstillvar1`, not to `var1/stillvar1`. This means you are double-encoding your values. You really need to read up on URL encoding. You are missing very basic knowledge and should not go on trying to solve problems that you do not understand the basis of.

Comment: @Tomalak, I understand that it is double encoded, I did that because that was one of the solutions for what is causing part of my problem, see solution2 on http://www.jampmark.com/web-scripting/5-solutions-to-url-encoded-slashes-problem-in-apache.html I should have mentioned that in my previous post, sorry

Answer (score 0):

How about the following regex?

```
((//|[^/])+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont clearly understand your requirement but as far as i understand try this (tested in robular)

```
^\w+\:\/{2}(\w+\.)+\w+(\/{1}\w+)+$
```